# Can't boot on bootable USB with Manjaro 17.0 Community Edition i3

Tags: boot, live-usb, manjaro, bootable

I would like to try this distribution. I made a bootable USB drive that I was able to use on my laptop, but I can't make it work on my main PC.

Here is a screenshot of what's happening at boot time.

[image]

I have to boot with kernel set to 'safe' to have this screen, otherwise I am stuck on a black screen.

Regarding...

```
Unable to init device /dev/mcelog (rc: -5)
```

It seems to be related with nouveau driver. I'm not sure it is the reason why the system cannot be initiated. I would rather use the proprietary driver later on anyway.

```
unable to locate ioapic for gsi 51
```

Seems to be related to 4.8 and harmless
(Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218566)

```
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
```

I tried what is advised [here](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error), but it was unsuccessful.

I also tried all USB ports.

From the UEFI menu I had two options to boot from my USB stick (Sandisk).

- UEFI Sandisk
- Sandisk

According to the one I pick it drives me to two possible screens.

[image]
<sup>**The UEFI option (screen 1)**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**The non UEFI option (screen 2)**</sup>

Comment: If you are in safemode, then you have started to boot Microsoft's windows.

Comment: Kernel mode is set to 'safe', manjaro offer the possibility to select this option when you boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors from the non UEFI mode in the end were misleading.
So far the UEFI path led me to blackscreen, but it is actually the one to pick. The problem is that with this grub you cannot modify kernel parameters on the fly by pressing *E*. Doing it bring a line *initrd=/.../ * with the path to initrd but you cannot scroll to the left or right to get to the options we are looking for. To specify the nomodeset option I had to modify *loader/entries/manjaro-[arch].conf and substitute

```
nouveau.modeset=1 i915.modeset=1 radeon.modeset=1
```

by

```
nomodeset=1
```

By doing that it keep the native resolution and you can see the log going on.
At some point it stopped at line

```
OK start account service
```

By doing *Ctrl+Alt+F2* you can get to a terminal windows and login as user *manjaro* pwd *manjaro*
From there you can acces journal

```
journalctl -b
```

And see what went wrong, in my case the driver of my graphic card are not taken into account properly

**EDIT**
Apparently nouveau do not handle my graphic card correctly but if you pick non-free driver it can work
In you bootable manjaro USB, in *loader/entries/manjaro-[arch]-**nonfree**.conf substitute

```
nouveau.modeset=1 i915.modeset=1 radeon.modeset=1
```

by

```
nomodeset=1
```

Reboot in UEFI mode, select Start Manjaro nonfree, and that's it!

Comment: this worked. i wasn't removing the `=1` stuff

Answer (score 1):

Pick the UEFI option only if you know exactly what you're doing. So pick the non-UEFI option, select the *Start Manjaro Linux* option, then follow below instructions.

Select the *Live CD* entry in the boot menu, press *E* on your keyboard and replace *quiet splash* with *nomodeset*. If you don't find *quiet splash*, just look for the second last line and place *nomodeset* after *ro*.

Comment: I updated the thread, I do not see where I have the opportunity to add such parameters. There is no grub bootloader so far. thanks anyway for helping

Comment: I have nowhere the opportunity to press E and do such a thing, once I pick Start Manjaro Linux I do not have hand anymore. Maybe it is something you can do with other kind of bootable distro, manjaro is based on arch linux which might include component you are not familiar with.

Comment: I updated the very end of the post so maybe you can help me booting in non UEFI mode form the HDD. thanks

Comment: I can also access the bootable device through grub thanks to my actual linux. From there I might add the parameter you are talking about. here is my actual boot entry : search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 5DD6-EE22
chainloader (${root})/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi

Comment: how should I add the parameter?

Comment: You can press E on every Linux. Select the *Start Manjaro Linux* boot entry, but DON'T start it, just select it. Then press E. It works.

Comment: Also there are some options by pressing F3 or F4, you can try those and see where it says *failsafe* or *nomodeset*.

Comment: I think the safemode does include the nomodeset option and this is why I can get message through this, which led me to the first screenshot. Why should I avoid UEFI mode?

Comment: You shouldn't avoid UEFI. But you should only use it, if you know how it works. Clearly you don't know how it works, that's why I recommended you to not use it. Did you try to boot from HDD with *nomodeset* on?

Comment: I see that you posted an enhanced version of my answer as a working solution. It would be kind, if you marked my solution as working.

Comment: You kept telling me to press E in the non-UEFI mode where it was not even possible and to avoid UEFI mode which in the end worked. I'll upvote you once I'll have the reputation to vote on this board because indeed the nomodeset was part of the solution. Thanks

Comment: As I said, I only recommended you to not use UEFI because it will cause problems if you install with UEFI now while not knowing what the difference from standard MBR and new UEFI is. If you know how to deal with UEFI, you're free to use it and I use it even myself! Also I would've given you a more elaborate answer but I wasn't home, so I had to hurry with typing.

Comment: But anyways, I'm happy to hear that you worked out things. People need more Linux and less Orwellian instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your live USB with etcher, it solved the boot issue for me (usb key shown no bootable files): https://etcher.io/